# Alloy specifications

Tags: software-design, alloy

I'm a beginner learning Alloy, I want to know what means this n.^address (maybe with an example)? because logically if we consider address as a set of pairs like (A0,A1), then how we can join n which is for example N0 with this set?! since the left most element of pairs in address are not the same nature with n, I supposed that it would not possible.
I'd really appreciate if anyone can guide me

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used alloy, but the `^` operator represents the transitive closure of its operand relation. So if `address` is `{(a,b), (b,c)}` then `^address` is `{(a,b), (b,c), (a,c)}`.

`n.^address` is the projection of the new relation on `n`.

So if `n` is `a`, then `n.^address` is `{b,c}`

Example:

```
abstract sig atom{
    address: lone atom
}
one sig a,b,c extends atom{}

fact {
    address = a->b + b->c
}

check {
    a.^address = b+c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask "what means this n.^address?"

The expression *n.^address* is a join between the set of tuples denoted by *n* and the set of tuples denoted by *^address*.

The expression *^address*, in turn, denotes the transitive closure of the relation *address*, i.e. the smallest relation containing *address* which is transitive.

Whether there is in fact, or can be in principle, any tuple in *n* whose rightmost value is the same as the leftmost value of some tuple in *^address* -- or, said another way, whether the expression *n.^address* is guaranteed to denote the empty set or not -- depends partly on how the variable *n* and the relation *address* are defined and partly on how the universe is populated.  The same is true for whether the transitive closure of *address* is the same as *address* or a larger relation.

If `N0`, `A0`, and `A1` are all atoms, and if the relation *address* contains only the pair `(A0, A1)`, and the expression *n* denotes (the singleton set containing) the atom `N0`, then indeed the expression *n.^address* will denote the empty set.  If on the other hand *address* contains a tuple `(N0, A0)` as well as the tuple `(A0, A1)`, then

- the expression *address* denotes the singleton set containing the tuple `(A0, A1)`,
- the expression *^address* also denotes the singleton set containing the tuple `(A0, A1)`, and
- the expression *n.^address* denotes the singleton set containing the tuple `(N0, A1)`, because the join of the set `{(N0, A0)}` with the set `{(A0, A1)}` is the set `{(N0, A1)}`.

Since you don't provide any more information about the Alloy model you have in mind, it's not possible to say much more.